# Did DICE ever fix the Battlefield 4 texture flickering?

Tags: pc, battlefield-4

Since Oct 2013 I have owned an AMD CPU and GPU desktop and now an Intel and Nvidia desktop and I have played on Mantle and DirectX and certain objects in the distance have always had bad flickering that ruins the great looks this game has. Whenever I google the issue I just see random forum posts with no definitive solutions or notes about a patch that fixed it. What gives? How can this glitch stand for nearly two years? I hope Battlefront 3 does not inherit it...

Comment: Are you currently experiencing this issue?  What is your current make/model of video hardware?

Comment: Geforce 970, I forget the drivers, I upgraded my Nvidia drivers once I got Witcher 3. I need to run "Test Range" again. Maybe tweaking AA on or off will fix it? I saw something about turning off AA post-processing option.

Comment: Absolutely no problems with my R9 280X. Playing since release, always updated driver when update availible.

Comment: I have done the same and with AMD and Nvidia GPUs with Mantle and DirectX. I even re-installed the game once when switching to a new SSD.